# Use Handlebars.js with Web Forms

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I need to figure out how to display JSON data from an ASPHX file into an 
ASPX file without using C#. My theory is that I am not able to run the JavaScript because of the order of loading. Using web forms, how can I use a handlebars template inside of an ASP control content placeholder? The below code does not return any HTML to the page.

**============= ASP CODE / HTML =============**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="unprocessed.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/Default.Master"  Inherits="SurplusApp.unprocessed" %>
 <asp:content ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" runat="server">
  <script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <div class="entry">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
     <div class="body">
      {{body}}
     </div>
    </div>
   </script>
 </asp:content>
```

**=============== JS CODE =================**

```
var source = $("#entry-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = { title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!" };
var html = template(context);
```

**Update #1:**

What I have discovered is that when using web form pages the content placeholder tag does not support the script tag `<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">` however, you can add the template code in your js file and render the template in your web dev console. An example of this can be found on the handlebars github page: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/

Comment: Why even use ASP at all then?

Comment: Because I already have a master page.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't return HTML to the page? You haven't shown an attempt to do that. You just stick it in a variable. Have you debugged your code? Tried appending the result to the DOM? Looked for errors in the console?

Comment: Nothing gets returned in the console. If you look at the ASP page you can see that I already have a script tag that is being referenced from the js code. I pulled this example from the handlebars website. Also, I see the same HTML in my dev tools, however {{title}} does not change nor does it print "{{title}}" to the page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a MIME type to your web.config file because a web forms page ASPX file with `<asp:content></asp:content>` does not support adding `<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">`
2. Create a Handlebars template file.
3. Create a div with a unique id which we will use later to insert our Handbars rendered template.
4. On the bottom of your ASPX page add a script tag and add two AJAX handlers, one to return the data from a JSON feed and another to return a handlebars template. In our second AJAX call, this is where we will append our newly created HTML from Handlebars.

   `var responseObject;`
   `$.get('jsonFeed.ashx', function(response){ responseObject = response });`
   `$.get('handlebarsTemplate.hbs', function(response){`
   `var template = Handlebars.compile(response);`
   `var handlebarTemplateInsert = template(responseObject);`
   `$('#element').append(handlebarTemplateInsert);`
   `});`